# How can one end a sequence by creating an empty line?

Tags: c#, list

> Read a sequence of positive numbers and the sequence ends when a blank
> line is created. Calculate sum and average of the numbers.

I tried this code but it's giving an **exception**.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> numbers = new List<string>();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter some numbers: ");

    string num = Console.ReadLine();
    int sum = 0;

    while (num != string.Empty)
    {
        numbers.Add(num);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
    {
        int numDigit = int.Parse(numbers[i]);
 
        if (numDigit < 0)
        {
            numDigit = Math.Abs(numDigit);
        }

        sum += i;
    }
   
    Console.WriteLine("The sum of the numbers is: {0}", sum);
    Console.WriteLine("The average of the numbers is: ", sum / numbers.Count);
    
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Surely you just keep reading until you read an empty line? Your `while (num != string.Empty)` will give you an infinite loop if `num != string.Empty` is true because `num` doesn't change in the loop.

Comment: _"I tried this code but its giving an exception."_ - You should include the exception in your question if you want help fixing it. After all, how can we fix the exception without knowing what it is?

Comment: If you just add `num = Console.ReadLine();` in your while loop. You will store the input in `numbers`, then wait for an other one.

Answer (score 4):

Let's split the initial problem into *simpler* ones: UI (user input) and business logic. Let's *extract the method* for this:

```
     private static List<int> ReadInts() {
       List<int> result = new List<int>();

       // We keep asking user...
       while (true) {
         string input = Console.ReadLine();

         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) // ... until empty string is provided
           return result;

         if (int.TryParse(input, out int item))
           result.Add(item); // valid integer; store it
         else
           Console.WriteLine("Syntax error. Please, try again"); 
       }
     }
```

Then you can put

```
     static void Main(string[] args) {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter some numbers: ");

       List<int> numbers = ReadInts(); 

       int sum = 0;

       foreach (int item in numbers)
         sum += item;

       Console.WriteLine("The sum of the numbers is: {0}", sum);
       Console.WriteLine("The average of the numbers is: {0}", sum / numbers.Count);
        
       Console.ReadKey();
     }
```